# Lock landscape view in Firefox OS?

Tags: orientation, firefox-os

I want to lock the screen of Firefox OS for landscape mode and neither one of the options below seems to work.

[image: Firefox OS app in the Firefox OS Simulator]

Uuh, not working it appears.

```
"orientation": ["landscape"],

{
    "name":"Poker",
    "description":"Lottery",
    "launch_path":"/videolottery.html",
    "version":"1.0",
    "orientation": ["portrait"],
    "developer":{
             "name":"Doug Hauf"
    },
    "icons":{
        "128":"/128_Pong.jpg"
    },
    "default_locale":"en"
}
```

New tried code. So far it did not let me switch the simulator to landscape mode. So this is locking the screen in portrait mode. I am read to put this game up but not the way it is currently.

```
{
    "name":"Poker",
    "description":"Lottery",
    "launch_path":"/videolottery.html",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "orientation": ["landscape-primary"],
    "developer":{
             "name":"Doug Hauf"
    },
    "icons":{
        "128":"/128K.jpg"
    },
    "default_locale":"en"
}
```

Comment: try "orientation": "landscape-primary" and I believe you have to switch the simulator to landscape manually.

Comment: I tried that and it was in landscape but the phone came up in portrait but it would not let me switch to landscape. I want it so when the game starts it is in landscape and cannot be changed just like on a pong game that I did and it was in portrait.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It might be simulator's issue. Can you try this on real device?

Comment: I purchased one but cannnot so far have not gotten it to update to the new version of the software thus it will not show on the device. Does this work on yours.

Comment: It could be the simulator I guess. I downloaded it once and then erased it and then downloaded it again.

Comment: What other devices use the Firefox OS plateform. Is it possible to install on a Nexus 7 without taking all of the other operating system out.

Answer (score 0):

At present there are two ways you can achieve this.

1. Manifest

> If you put   "orientation": "landscape" in manifest file it will lock
>   the orientation to landscape (you do not need the primary or secondary
>   notion yet)

2. JavaScript

> ```
> var orientation = function() {
>     if (window.screen.mozLockOrientation('landscape')) {
>          // orientation was locked
>     } else {
>         screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
>     }
> }
> ```

I have used both in two of my seperate published apps. (though only used the former one for landscape, latter one I used o fix it in portrait.
I would suggest to go for the first one since the latter one seems to have problem (not supported) in Firefox for Desktop.

Tested in simulator 1.4,2.0 and 2.2